# My javascript function won't update a global variable. Why is this so?

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, global-variables

For context, I am trying to get the user ID and assign it within the database, which is a success. Next, when I call the 'userID' variable after the function (see console log), it doesn't appear to have updated from the first declaration.

```
      var userID = 'test';
  
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      userID = user.uid;
      let x = db.collection('users').doc(userID);
      x.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            x.update({Logins: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
            'Last login': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
            return userID;
        } else {
            // adding Login count
            x.set({Logins: 1, 'Whispers Received': 0});
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
      
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
  });

  console.log(userID);
```

The 'console.log' prints "test" instead of the user's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to asynchronous world of JavaScript + event loop.

Your `console.log(userID)` happens before the callback function `function(user)` inside `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` can be triggered. So you will always get `userId` as `'test'`. This is expected behaviour.

To explore this in detail, head over to:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing

Comment: Oh man, that is so not cool. I tried my best to keep up with the link and the last part helped most. Now it makes sense. I'm thinking I either put my event listeners (these come after the console log) into the 'If' condition. The other option (if this makes sense) is I can put a function around the console log (and event listeners) and call that function, and within the function I ensure that if 'userID' === 'test' then loop and do that function again.

Comment: Nevermind this approach - I used a 'while loop' and it led to a limit on how man times the browser will run the process before shutting it down.

Comment: Figured it out! so I put a function around the entire code and called it within my 'sign in' function. If the user ID exists then I allow the rest of the code to run (except for DOM functions - these I kept outside it).